# Meaning of "This is you" in Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow

Tags: meaning, andrews-brain, e-l-doctorow

In Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow:

> Another morning. I am down on the beach as the osprey hovers pulsingly
> over the sea, and the sanderlings tiptoe along the ocean’s foamy edge
> while the shadowing bluefish waits for the tide to flip them into its
> razored maw.
>
> **This is you, God**. And who did you say it was, Jonah, riding the struts
> of the leviathan? With the tons of fish washing beneath him into the
> digestive caldron, as he plants one foot on one beamy rib, the other
> on the other, and it would be dark except for the luminescence of the
> electric fishes looking to find their way out, against the tide,
> against the moonrock slurp of the ocean tide, against the diurnal
> twist of the rumbling planet that cups the ocean, that nods the
> mountains back and forth in metronomic rhythm …

What does he mean by "**This is you, God**"?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the previous paragraph, the one starting "Another morning"? That paragraph provides some context for the sentence you asked about.

Comment: So do you mean that he is talking about the previous paragraph, when he says "This is you, God"?

Comment: Normally "this" refers backwards so that's what I would expect.